# $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\sin^{k}x\sec^{k-n}{x}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions, trigonometric-series

Let $n$ be a non-negative integer and let $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\sin^{k}x\sec^{k-n}{x}.$$
Prove that $f(x)$ is periodic and find its amplitude.

---

I don't really know how to start, and all I did was write $\sin^{k}x\sec^{k-n}{x}$ as $\sin^k x\cos^{n-k}x$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here, and any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** Use the binomial theorem:

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k x^k y^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to @EeveeTrainer's comment, you can express the proposed sum as
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\sin^{k}(x)\sec^{k-n}(x)\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\sin^{k}(x)\cos^{n-k}(x)\\\\
& = (\sin(x) + \cos(x))^{n}\\\\
& = 2^{n/2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(x)\right)^{n}\\\\
& = 2^{n/2}\sin^{n}\left(x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: You changed $\sec^{k-n}(x)$ to $\sec^{n-k}(x)$.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for pointing that out! I am going to fix that typo.